# Using GetActiveWindow()

Tags: vb.net, winforms, loops, infinite-loop, user32

I have a timer in my application (timer1). When this timer goes off, it calls a sub that refreshes my datagridview. Before calling the refresh sub, I use GetActiveWindow() from user32 Lib to check If the form is the active window. This works as expected. Here is the code I am using to check the active window.

```
If Me.Handle = GetActiveWindow() Then
    gridRefresh()
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Works")
End If
```

I included the messagebox just to give me a visual that It is indeed working when the active window is not my Application.

What I am missing though is I would like to call the gridRefresh() sub once my Application becomes the active window again.

My first thought would be to use a Do Until loop and have it do nothing until It becomes the active window again like so:

```
If Me.Handle = GetActiveWindow() Then
    gridRefresh()
Else
    Do Until Me.Handle = GetActiveWindow()

    Loop
    gridRefresh()
End If
```

But when I try this solution It never comes out of the loop.

Edit: The timer interval is 1 minute. The reason I want it to refresh once it becomes active again is so the user doesn't have to wait a whole minute to see if anything has been added to the gridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing this correctly, Winforms already supports all this.  No need for pinvoke, you can use the Form.ActiveForm property.  And the Activate and Deactivate events tell you that a form is de/activated.   Put this code in the form that contains the grid:

```
    protected override void OnDeactivate(EventArgs e) {
        // Runs when the window is deactivated.  Stop the timer
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        base.OnDeactivate(e);
    }

    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e) {
        // Runs when the window is activated.  Start the timer and immediately refresh
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1_Tick(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        base.OnActivated(e);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Periodically refresh the grid
        gridRefresh();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. After converting to vb This worked fine. Out of curiosity, do you know why minimizing the form does not de-activate the form? No issue I just used the minimize and maximize events, But I figured minimizing the form would de-activate it as well..

Comment: Never mind. It does get de-activated when minimized. Apologies

Answer (score 1):

You can add two `Boolean` fields to your form class, called `Active` and `RefreshRequired`.

Then add handlers to the form's [`Activated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Deactivate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events. The `Deactivate` event handler just sets `Active` false. The `Activated` event handler looks like:

```
Active = True
If RefreshRequired Then
   gridRefresh()
   RefreshRequired = False
End If
```

Finally you re-write your original code as :

```
If Active Then
    gridRefresh()
Else
    RefreshRequired = True
End If
```